# Parsing 中村さんは私を相撲を見に連れて行ってくださいました

Tags: meaning, parsing

Can someone break down this Japanese sentence into simpler parts?

> 中村さんは私を相撲を見に連れて行ってくださいました。

I was stuck at the 私を相撲を, didn't realize that it's about watching sumo that's why there were two をs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 中村さんは私を相撲を見に**連れて行ってくださいました**。

The basic form of the given sentence is as:

> 中村さんは私を相撲を見に連れて行く。

If you parse the sentence, you'll get it as follows.

> 中村さんは　*Mr./Ms. Nakamura*
>   私を　　　　*me*
>   相撲を見に　*to watch sumo matches*
>   連れて行く　*takes*

**連れて行ってくださいました** is the past tense form of 連れて行ってくださいます.
連れて行ってくださいます is the polite form (丁寧形｛ていねいけい｝) of 連れて行ってくださる.
連れて行ってくださる is the honorific/respectful form (尊敬語) of 連れて行ってくれる.

The relation between 連れて行ってくれる and 連れて行く is explained precisely [here](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/27588/why-can-story-writers-use-%E3%81%8F%E3%82%8C%E3%82%8B-when-describing-a-third-person).

Comment: `連れて行ってくださいました is a polite form of 連れて行く` <-- 連れていってくださいました is the polite form (丁寧形) of 連れていってくださった. 連れていってくださった is the honorific/respectful form (尊敬語) of 連れていってくれた. (くださる is the honorific form/尊敬語 of くれる)